# can Atom feed be read from the wso2esb

Tags: wso2-esb

To enable data Integration between two systems need to read Atom feed and publish that data to the Topic or Queue. Is there a way to read the Atom feed via wso2esb for achieve this ?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WSO2 ESB feed inbound and connector for this purpose. Details on how to configure this to read from atom feeds can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Feed+Inbound+and+Connector)

You can use the [feed inbound](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Feed+Inbound+Operations) to poll from the atom feed